# GDAL GetNoDataValue from HDF5 band

Tags: python, gdal, hdf

I am opening HDF5 file like this:

```
import gdal
hdf_ds = gdal.Open("myhdf.h5", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
band_ds = gdal.Open(hdf_ds.GetSubDatasets()[0][0], gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
```

In documentation it is said that `GDALRasterBand class` has a method `GetNoDataValue()`, but i can't get a band from it. I mean no such a method on my `band_ds` and when I'm trying to get a band from `band_ds` by `GetRasterBand()` it returns `NoneType` object. Should I do something more to get a `GDALRasterBand class` from my `band_ds`?

REF: https://gdal.org/doxygen/classGDALRasterBand.html#abf5ddfd58352f8b2f98af8ab48786d9c

Comment: The GDAL autotests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gdrivers/hdf5.py contain lot of working Python examples.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but there is nothing about checking NoData value in these tests

Comment: First you need to have a band. Do you have it now?

Comment: As I said `GetRasterBand()` returns `NoneType`, tried params 0 and 1

Comment: What does gdalinfo find from that subdataset? If autotests are using explicit subdataset names  `ds = gdal.Open('HDF5:"data/hdf5/CSK_GEC.h5"://S01/QLK')` perhaps it is worth trying the same syntax.

Comment: sorry but that is not a solution for me, would have to rewrite whole library

Comment: Don't give up. You can do it but you must think and do it right. Why it feels so bad to read the names of subdatasets, put them into some variable, pick the name of one subdataset from there and insert it into gdal.Open, then get the raster band, then get the nodata value? But if you want rather write your own library it is naturally OK.

Comment: Can you also supply the code where you tried `GetRasterBand()` please?